# ionic 3 keep socket connections open on backgrounded app

Tags: android, firebase, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing an app, if user activates background mode (press a button), app will each hour send some data to firebase. I have tested with shorter time-frame (each 5 mins), and for few times it updates (adds data to firebase), but after (~10 mins) stops to update. Once I reopen my app, at once it sends bunch of data to firebase.

I assume that OS (Android) closes socket connections on backgrounded app. I have tried to do `firebase.database().goOnline();`, but I guess firebase has no once app is on background mode. Is there a way to open socket connection and send data to firebase?

to enable background mode

```
import { BackgroundMode } from '@ionic-native/background-mode'; 

constructor(public backgroundMode: BackgroundMode){}

    private setupBackgroundMode() {
        this.backgroundMode.enable();
        this.backgroundMode.excludeFromTaskList();
        this.backgroundMode.setDefaults({ hidden: true, silent: true });
      }
```

Comment: Your assumption is correct - mobile platforms “icebox” app activity for background apps and there are only select few processes that can be allowed to act in background: geolocation, ble etc. But even these processes are heavily regulated and prescribed. So what you are trying to achieve with websockets is hardly possible, best bet id to pull data update on resume.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The idea of the a app is to be able to work on background for a long time and might be opened once in few month.

Comment: Understand, but you will have to figure out other (serverside) ways to do compute for your client apps, clearly there is a trend with all security concerns to prevent apps doing anything in the background. Days of true multitasking are sort of gone for mobile, maybe Android would allow you that though

Comment: Another reason for mobile platform to strict control apps in background aside security - is battery life. All mobile devices compete to provide linger usage time and something in background eating battery via connection is exactly the opposite of what vendors want.

Comment: You are completely right, but I was thinking of "open connection -> save the data -> close the connection" scenario. This seems not possible.